# How to install, setup, and configure lamp server in 2021?

Tags: lamp

How to install, setup and configure the last version of **lamp** server in 2021?
Note: This is my first time, I don't install any version before (i.e I'm biginner).
For setup, let use 'lailaba.com' as my domain name & 'about.lailaba.com as subdomain name as example.

Comment: StackOverflow is for questions about programming, not software setup.  Try http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

[LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle)) just stands for Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP/Perl/Python, so you need to choose a Linux distribution that provides Apache, MySQL, and PHP/Perl/Python (whatever of these you need). Many distributions nowadays don't provide MySQL, but the MariaDB fork instead. You can probably just use that fork.

For example, Debian is a suitable distribution and there is a [guide](https://www.tecmint.com/install-lamp-on-debian-10-server/) to install these packages (assuming PHP for P). It's from 2019, but that is probably recent enough.